# How does $(x^3 + 8)^{-2/3} = 0$ become $(x^3 + 8) = 0$? Can a negative exponent always be simply dropped?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

It was explained to me that if:
$$(x^3 + 8)^{-2/3} = 0$$
then
$$(x^3 + 8) = 0$$

...  In other words, the negative fractional exponent can simply be dropped from the expression. What are the exact rules that apply to this statement?

**Can a negative exponent ALWAYS be simply dropped from the expression or are there more stipulations that need to be accounted for when making the determination?**

Comment: What is the value of $0^{-2/3}$?

Comment: "It was explained to me " Erm, *who* did this?

Comment: That's not how math works. If you want to use a rule without knowing why it exists, then you will use it wrong.

Comment: If $k$ is positive than $M^{-k} =0\implies \frac 1{M^k} = 0$ which is not possible.  $M^w = 0$ is only possible if $w>0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone explained something to you incorrectly. And worse, they led you to believe something that is false is true.

If $$Q^{-2/3}=0$$ then recognize what negative exponents indicate: $$\frac{1}{Q^{2/3}}=0$$

So $1$ was divided by something and the result was $0$. There is no number $Q$ where this happens.

So your equation has no solution, unlike the other equation $(x^3+8)=0$ which does have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the negative sign *can* validly be dropped from the exponent if the exponent identically equals $0,$ or if the base or the base raised to the exponent identically equals $1,$ or if the base identically equals $-1$ and the exponent is an integer.

But, as suggested by Ivan in the comments, such an inelegant rule is less useful than simply understanding the exponent laws properly.

P.S. [$(x^3 + 8)^{-2/3} = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+%28x%5E3+%2B+8%29%5E%7B-2%2F3%7D+%3D+0) does not imply [$(x^3 + 8) = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+%28x%5E3+%2B+8%29%3D+0), since the the latter equation (having $3$ solutions) fails to capture the fact that the former has no solution.

P.P.S. Conversely, [$(x^3 + 8) = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+%28x%5E3+%2B+8%29%3D+0) does not imply [$(x^3 + 8)^{-2/3} = 0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+%28x%5E3+%2B+8%29%5E%7B-2%2F3%7D+%3D+0) either, since the former's solution set is not a subset of the latter's.